# How to call another activity after certain time limit

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to give time limit for calling one activity to another activity. I want to call another activity (Ex calling A class to B class) by given some time limit. I used alarmManager, but it is not possible for my application also i used threading, whenever i give Thread.sleep it will not perform action till the sleep getting end.  I am not sure how to do this process. can anyone give a idea of giving time limit to calling a class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and add a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that is executed after a specific delay.

Here is a more or less completed example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

   public void run() {

      //here you can start your Activity B.

   }

}, 10000);
```

The example above executes a new TimerTask in 10 seconds. Inside the TimerTask you can override the run method. In the run method you can start your new activity. The run method is executed after the delay. In this example it is 10'000 milliseconds.

Comment: @Roflcoptr I tried this, but whenever the time getting end, it shows force close error. It will never goes to activity B. i dont know where is the mistake. pls guide me.. Thanks for your immediate replies ....

Comment: @HariRam you have to post the logcat, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: `WARN/dalvikvm(4645): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)`

Comment: `ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at com.example.Task.jokedescription$1.run(jokedescription.java:186)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.example.Task/.jokedescription`

Comment: It's getting complicated. I personally would recommend to open a new questions where you post the code inside the run method above and the the oncreate method of your new activity you start there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486284/how-to-solve-fatal-exception :- pls check this url

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simply solution.  this could be used for example for showing a splash activity for 1 second then  going into the main app:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            int secondsDelayed = 1;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, ActivityB.class));
                            finish();
                    }
            }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using android `CountDownTimer` class.

See this example for a 3 second delay.

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
    public void onFinish() {
         Intent startActivity = new Intent(ThisActivity.this,ActivityToStart.class);
         startActivity(startActivity);
        finish();
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }

}.start();
```

You may also need to define your parent activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file,

```
<activity
      android:name=".ActivityToStart"
      android:label="Back"
      android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

      <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
      <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: `startActivity(startActivity);` is this a recursive function?

Answer (score 1):

Let's hope following example may help.

Here I have call `MainActivity.java` after **certain time** (2 seconds in this example) from `MainPage.java`

## CODE:

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        Handler handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainPage.this,MainActivity.class));
            }
        },2000L);
    }

}
```