# How to solve fatal exception

Tags: android

```
    WARN/dalvikvm(4645): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at com.example.Task.jokedescription$1.run(jokedescription.java:186)
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4645):     at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
    WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.example.Task/.jokedescription
```

Comment: Code around this line would also be great: at com.example.Task.jokedescription$1.run(jokedescription.java:186)

Comment: Sorry i cant get you properly.. what is that jokedescription.java:186

Comment: This should be in your code were you try to display a toast.

Comment: I  just checked this code by giving toast message.. what can i do now. will i delete the toast and link the activity.??

Comment: Yes If you would post that code we could find your error.

Comment: Thank you guys, i got the solution. whenever i link the activity i would'nt get any error. incase if i give toast message, it displays the exception

Comment: @HariRam the reason for that was posted by Maxim. You're showing a Toast nor from the main threa.d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to show a Toast not from main (UI) thread.

Please post the snippet of code you have exception in.