# [android]Notification Send time

Tags: android, notifications

I have typed the code below in order to post a notification, I wish to know how to make it send after 5 minutes for example.

I have tried to use the when commend but as it seems I don't know how to use it.

Can anyone explain me how it is done?
Thank you very much :)

```
   @Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();


    NotificationCompat.Builder Nbuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Where you gone?")
        .setContentText("We miss you, Come back!")
        .setWhen(60000);

    int NbuilderId = 1;
    NotificationManager mNotifyMngr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMngr.notify(NbuilderId,Nbuilder.build());

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5485705/1168654

Comment: How does the timer task help me?, cause I want it to send a notification after I'm not in the app anymore after lets say 5 minutes.